# Why is the tensor product of admissible homomorphisms of seminormed A-modules admissible?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a normed ring, and let $M$ and $N$ be seminormed $A$-modules. If $\phi:M'\rightarrow M$ and $\psi:N'\rightarrow N$ are admissible homomorphisms of seminormed $A$-modules, then I want to show that the induced homomorphism $M'\otimes_A N'\rightarrow M\otimes_A N$ is admissible. That is, I want to show that the residue seminorm on $M'\otimes_A N'/\ker (\phi \otimes \psi)$ is equivalent to the restriction to $\text{Im}(\phi\otimes\psi)$ of the seminorm on $M\otimes_A N$.

$\phi$ and $\psi$ being admissible means that there exist constants $B, B', C, C'$ such that for all $m \in M'$, $n \in N'$

$B \; |\phi(m)|_M \leq \inf \{|m'|_{M'} \; | \: \phi(m')=\phi(m)\} \leq B'\;|\phi(m)|_M$

$C \; |\psi(n)|_N \leq \inf \{|n'|_{N'} \; | \: \psi(n')=\psi(n)\} \leq C'\;|\psi(n)|_N$

Now, it's easy to get the lower bound on the residue seminorm $|\;|_{res}$ on on $M'\otimes_A N'/\ker (\phi \otimes \psi)$. Given $f\in \text{Im}(M\otimes_A N)$, we have

$|f|_{res}=\inf \{ \sum|m_i||n_i|\; : \;f=(\phi\otimes\psi)(\sum m_i \otimes n_i) \} \\ \geq \inf\{ BC \sum |\phi(m_i)|_M|\psi(n_i)|_N \; : \; f=\sum \phi(m_i)\otimes \psi(n_i)\} \\ 
\geq BC\inf\{ \sum |m_i'|_M|n_i'|_N \; : \; f=\sum m_i'\otimes n_i'\} \\ =BC|f|_{M\otimes N}$

But to get the other inequality, I feel like I have no control over how small $\sum |m_i|_M|n_i|_N$ might be for $f=\sum m_i \otimes n_i$, since these $m_i$ and $n_i$ need not be in the images of $\phi$ and $\psi$.

All my definitions come from Chapter 1 of Berkovich's *Spectral Theory and Analytic Geometry over Non-Archimedean Fields*.

Comment: what is the field you are using here?

Comment: I don't have a field (don't need one for Berkovich's treatment), but I'm using the archimedean seminorm on my tensor product. If my semi norms were all non-archimedean, I'd use $|f|=\inf\{\max |m_i|\;|n_i|\; | \: f=\sum m_i\otimes n_i\}$, but I think this works out the same?